# Good android graphical layout editor

Tags: android, eclipse, user-interface

I am working on android development, I need a good UI designer which is easy to use.

What is a good UI graphical editor for Android? for OSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the options are the eclipse plugin (ADT) and DroidDraw.

Comment: Unless they made gigantic advancements in progress, the Eclipse plug-in (ADT) is still a terrible tool to use as a UI graphical editor for Android.

Comment: Have you checked ADT 11? Its much better now.

Answer (score 7):

ADT 11 was released yesterday(06 June 2011).

here you can watch adt 11 version tools demo on Google I/O:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/new-editing-features-in-eclipse-plug-in.html

I think it has come close to what we'd expect. Personally, I am really impressed.

Answer (score 2):

The eclipse plugin has made **Dramatic** improvements in the last couple of versions. 
ADT 11 of the plugin has some great stuff mentioned in this video: [here](http://developer.android.com/videos/index.html#v=Oq05KqjXTvs).
[here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) is a good summary of the changes / improvements made in ADT 11. You'll also need version 11 of the sdk tools, available [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/tools-notes.html).